# Android loading the same bitmap images crash

Tags: android, bitmap, handler, face-detection

I am a beginner in Android app dev. Recently I am trying to make a face detection app using FaceDetector. 

In the code below is my main activity class. I have a Runnable to loop through a set of images, convert to bitmaps and send them to FaceOverlayView to find and draw faces. The loop can go through all 4 items. 

However, as I tried to make it loop all over again by setting index to 0 after the last item, the app crashes. I observed the behavior that the app will **crash trying to reload an image loaded before**. Would you please give me any insight on this? Many thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FaceOverlayView mFaceOverlayView;

    Handler handler;
    Thread thread;
    ArrayList<Integer> imgID = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(R.raw.face1, R.raw.face2, R.raw.face3, R.raw.face4));


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFaceOverlayView = (FaceOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.face_overlay);
        thread = new Thread(new myThread());
        thread.start();
        handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.arg1 == -1) {
                    //thread.interrupt();
                }
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) msg.obj;
                mFaceOverlayView.setBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        };
    }

    class myThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int index = 0;
            while (index < imgID.size()) {
                InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(imgID.get(index));
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.obj = bitmap;


                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                index++;
                if (index >= imgID.size()) {
                    index = 0;
                }
                bitmap.recycle();
                bitmap = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When loading bitmaps, I ususally call recycle() and bitmap = null in activities onDestroy(). Please try that

Comment: show your stacTrace